# Executing binary SQL file using SQLCMD from WiX

Tags: binary, wix, sqlcmd

I'm trying to install SQL script(SSDT) using SQLCMD - as this script contains to many SSDT definitions and cannot be run by the WIX SQL extension.
i want my SQL script file to be binary(as i don't want it to stay on target machine)

how can i set the SQLCMD command to use the binary script (with -i)?

p.s.

i tried this blog:
http://neilsleightholm.blogspot.co.il/2008/08/executing-sqlcmd-from-wix.html##

but this code don't shows the link between the binary SQL file and the SCLCMD command.
can someone help me with the correct code?

this is the code i used, which did not work for me

```
<Binary Id="CreateSchema.sql"  SourceFile="..\SQL\CreateSchema.sql" />

<CustomAction Id="sqlcmd.cmd"
          Property="sqlcmd"
          Value="&quot;sqlcmd.exe&quot; -S [DATABASE_SERVER]
        -i &quot;[#CreateSchema.sql]&quot; -v var=SYSTEM_USER -o [INSTALLDIR]installSql.log" />


<CustomAction Id="sqlcmd"
          BinaryKey="WixCA"
          DllEntry="CAQuietExec"
          Return="check"
          Execute="deferred"
          Impersonate="yes" />

<InstallExecuteSequence> 
  <Custom Action="sqlcmd.cmd" After="InstallFiles">NOT Installed</Custom>
  <Custom Action="sqlcmd" After="sqlcmd.cmd">NOT Installed</Custom>
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

the log file showed that -i parameter did not had any file name value:

MSI (s) (4C:6C) [09:58:15:610]: Executing op: CustomActionSchedule(Action=sqlcmd,ActionType=1025,Source=BinaryData,Target=CAQuietExec,CustomActionData="sqlcmd.exe" -S (local) **-i ""** -v var=SYSTEM_USER -o C:\installSql.log)

Comment: That indicates the file was not found, are you sure the file ID associated to the CreateSchema.sql file is actually correct?

Comment: yes it is, the same id, and also i checked both the id and the binary file in binary table(opened with orca.exe)

Comment: You mention you don't want the sql file to stick around after, you haven't excluded it in an absent component have you? Looking at [Formatted](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/aa368609.aspx) that is the only thing I can think of.

Comment: thanks, it helped my understood it better.

Answer (score 1):

That's not how `<Binary>` works. The `[#FileID]` syntax is used to dynamically use the at runtime installation full path of a component's file.

Binaries are used typically as temporary extracted files for custom actions or, in this case, sql files among other things.

Consider looking into the SQL Extension in wix. As a minimal example take a look at this code.

Add the sql namespace `xmlns:sql="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/SqlExtension"`

```
<Binary Id="CreateSchema" SourceFile="..\SQL\CreateSchema.sql" />
<sql:SqlDatabase Id="MyDB" Database="[DATABASE]" Server="[DATABASE_SERVER]" />
```

And in a component you can add

```
<sql:SqlScript  Id="CreateSchemaScript" BinaryKey="CreateSchema" ExecuteOnInstall="yes" Sequence="1" SqlDb="MyDB"/>
```

[Here](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/sql/) is a link to the SQL Schema definition with all the available elements. I haven't done much with the SQL Extension so you may need to do some reading to get a better idea of what you will need to do to accomplish creating your DB on install.

Comment: thanks, i did not used the sqlExtension as it doesn't serves me well, as my sql script is in SSDT format and can only run using SQLCMD. you can see the answer i attache ahead.

Answer (score 1):

As i mentioned i wanted to use both SQLCMD - since my SQL script is SSDT format, and binary file(so file will be deleted in end of the install).

After looking for answers i understood that i cannot use the WiX [#filekey], as binary file will not be extracted as long as there is no custom action that is running  - using it explicitly.
So in the end i understood that the best way is to extract the binary file by my self.
the steps i used in one single custom action are:

1. extract binary SQL script from MSI binary table.
2. save this file locally
3. run SQLCMD with -i and new file path(the one i save to)
4. delete the SQL file

I encounter some issues, worth mentioned, if you save the file to INSTALLDIR than the directory may not exist at the tun time of the custom action, so consider save it to temp folder or to create directory beforehand.